# get the sys_file_metadata values using typo3 repository methods

Tags: repository, typo3-7.6.x

I am building an extension using typo3. I got stuck at one point. That is, I need the sys_file_metadata value along with sys_file informations. I am getting sys_file informations using repository methods. But not getting the metadata informations like title, description.

Can anyone help me to find a repository method to fetch metadata informations using repository methods?

```
 $storageRepository = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository'); // create instance to storage repository
   $storage = $storageRepository->findByUid(2);    // get file storage with uid 1 (this should by default point to your fileadmin/ directory)
   $folder = $storage->getFolder('/Audios/',false);
   $files = $storage->getFilesInFolder($folder);
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
       $array_file = $files[$key]->toArray();
       $uid = $array_file['uid'];
       $array['name'] = $array_file['name'];
       $array['extension'] = $array_file['extension'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. We can use the method

```
$value->_getMetaData();
```

To get the specified properties, we can use

```
$value->getProperty('description');
```